# ExecuteNonQuery() returns -1 from Oracle Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have the following part of code in my `.net C# console app`

```
var SGCodProdInsert = new OracleCommand
                        {
                            Connection = con,
                            CommandText = ProductFirstInsert,                                
                            CommandTimeout = 15,
                            Transaction = dbContextTransaction
                        };
                        var t = SGCodProdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The `Oracle` command(`ProductFirstInsert`) that i pass is like this:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Products_TEST (ProductName,ProductCode) VALUES ('TEST','TEST');
INSERT INTO Products_TEST (ProductName,ProductCode) VALUES ('TEST1','TEST1');
INSERT INTO Products_TEST (ProductName,ProductCode) VALUES ('TEST2','TEST2');
```

.

.

.

```
 INSERT INTO Products_TEST (ProductName,ProductCode) VALUES ('TESTn','TESTn');
 END;
```

As a result in `t` i get -1 and i can understand why...So my question is the following: 
How can I take in single integer how many records have inserted in my table from an oracle procedure ?

Comment: Oracle has an implicit cursor attribute to do this `SQL%ROWCOUNT`. this would give the count of row on which DML occured

Comment: @XING ok...so how should i modify my code ?

Comment: Are you calling a named procedure or an anonymous block? Can you have it populate a bind variable? (I don't know C#.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to execute a `count(*)` command before and after your command:

```
var SGCodProdInsert = new OracleCommand
{
    Connection = con,
    CommandText = ProductFirstInsert,
    CommandTimeout = 15,
    Transaction = dbContextTransaction
};
var CountTable = new OracleCommand
{
    Connection = con,
    CommandText = "select count(*) from Products_TEST",
    CommandTimeout = 15,
    Transaction = dbContextTransaction
};
decimal beforeInsert = Convert.ToDecimal(CountTable.ExecuteScalar());
SGCodProdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
decimal afterInsert = Convert.ToDecimal(CountTable.ExecuteScalar());

Console.WriteLine($"Inserted rows: {afterInsert - beforeInsert}");
```

Otherwise you would have to create a temporary Oracle function and read `SQL%ROWCOUNT`

Comment: I managed to find a solution.. but i was curious if i could do with a single command like `var test = SGCodProdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();`. Your answer though works only for insert command... But what about Update command ? Is there something general that you can use for both Insert and Update ? Anyway i will mark your answer as correct

Comment: I think if you want to check for update counts, you need to install a temporary Oracle function. See: https://csharpdeveloper.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/getting-values-back-from-oracle-procedures-in-c-net/

Answer (score 0):

For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.

The own Doc from Microsoft is saying this.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1